# Rails 3/ Git/ Bundler Fatal could not parse object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

When attempting bundle install I recieve the following error

```
Fatal could not parse object '8c11dd........
Git error: command git reset --hard '8c11dd

If this error persists you can try removing the cache directory.
```

Have removed the cache directory with no success, has anyone seen this error before?

Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Is that single quote a typo?  That would certainly cause a problem.

Comment: To clarify, something in them Gemfile points to a git ref 8c11dd, but there's a spurious single quote in there.

Comment: Sorry guys, to clarify that should be '8c11dd........'
Its a long hash following by a closing quote

Comment: Ah right. Are you 100% that git reference exists in the repo it points to?  Git doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your Gemfile contents?

Comment: try checking out the repo yourself and do a reset hard on the commit you defined.

Answer (score 32):

Ran into the same error when I moved repositories across servers. Resolved it by deleting the Gemfile.lock and running `bundle install`. This generated an updated Gemfile.lock that helped resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same issue and was trying a bunch of different things but forget this simple one. Got it working.

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock is usually a bad idea. When you run `bundle install` again it's going to grab the latest versions of any unspecified gems. Which will quite likely cause some headaches.

Comment: Agree with Tony. When I encountered this error, it was not an issue running 'bundle install' in my project. A better alternative will be to use 'bundle update <gemname>'.

Comment: If you don't actually want to update the gem in question or delete your Gemfile.lock because it has important version information, I recommend inspecting and manually editing the Gemfile.lock, finding the bad revision/commit hash, and then updating it to a correct one as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Capistrano removing the (shared/)cached-copy should solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Many of the posters here are correct in that it has most likely has to do with the Gemfile.lock being out of sync due to a repository moving or relocating, but like others pointed out, deleting it isn't a wise decision.  Inspect the Gemfile.lock and find a GIT entry for the repo in question.  The important thing to check is what the `revision` metadata attribute it points to...  It is most likely pointing to a bad revision hash that no longer exists.

My advice is to manually edit it to point to the branch that you want to pull down by cross-referencing it with actual Repo's logfile (so you make sure it's consistent with the one that's actually in your actual Gemfile) as follows:

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/YourUserOrOrganization/your-gem-repo.git
  revision: <UPDATE AND FIX ME!>
  specs:
    some-random-dep1 (2.4.3)
      some-random-dep2 (>= 1.7.9)
      some-random-dep3 (>= 1.6.7)
```

Answer (score 5):

Something must've happened to the repository. In my case it was removed/moved. So I just changed the `git` url.

If your `:git =>` is pointing to github, might be a good idea to visit that github project's page.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with Capistrano using `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache` when I've switched to different github fork of repository.

My capistrano recipe was pointing to new fork, but cache on remote servers was still having `origin` pointing to old repository, and therefore it was not finding new commits I've pushed to new fork.

Fixed by executing on each of the remote servers:

`git remote set-url origin <new fork>`

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when there have been changes like force-pushes to a git repo which is referenced in a Gemfile.

The solution is is to comment that gem line in Gemfile, run bundle, uncomment it and bundle again. Then the Gemfile.lock will reference a valid git revision.

I guess it will help too: 
`bundle update my_gem_name`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the git branch that I was using for a gem had been merged into master and the branch deleted. Updating my `Gemfile`, removing `Gemfile.lock`, and re-running `bundle` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the '--source' flag with 'bundle update'.  So it will be:

`bundle update --source your_gem`

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building a gem and the problem was a little different from the other answers.

I target a specific version in the `Gemfile` but for development purpose I changed the `bundle config` to get the local version. I setup a different version on my local machine which makes the `Gemfile.lock` target something else in the `specs`.

This file is sent through the server via git and the server obviously can't access such version of the gem ...

To fix it, just specify a `VERSION` in your gem accordingly to the one you're developping / pushing on and it should be fine.

```
gem "my-gem", git: "https://github.com/Loschcode/my-gem.git", branch: "master", tag: "v0.2.2"
```