# Bundler: fatal: Could not parse object when gem uses github option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bundler, gemfile

When I do `bundle install` I get this:

```
fatal: Could not parse object 'f3412a7ffb015df7ced6aa662a53a53e081611a0'.
Git error: command `git reset --hard f3412a7ffb015df7ced6aa662a53a53e081611a0` in directory /Users/jd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/by_star-f3412a7ffb01 has failed.
Revision f3412a7ffb015df7ced6aa662a53a53e081611a0 does not exist in the repository https://github.com/radar/by_star.git. Maybe you misspelled it?
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/jd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/by_star-0bcdc3b24e4d129a7d7c5bce95c0a4a80393cdfd'
```

This happens from a gem included like this: `gem 'by_star', github: 'radar/by_star'`. If I remove the `github` option, the error disappears. This happens in two different projects, with different gems, always with the `git` or `github` option added. I followed the instruction in the error message as well (removing the cache directory) and still it happens.

I've already checked these answers to no avail:

- [fatal: Could not parse object #1304](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/1304)
- [fatal: could not parse object 'githashstring333111deadbeefc0ffee' #760](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/760)
- [Rails 3/ Git/ Bundler Fatal could not parse object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742442/rails-3-git-bundler-fatal-could-not-parse-object)

Anyone else has seen this persistent error?